# CSS for placing divs in the middle of a screen centered div and the edge of the screen

Tags: html, css

Here is the code:

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 30px;
}

#middle {
  width: 420px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 100px auto 0;
  border: solid;
}

#left {
  position: fixed;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 0;
}

#right {
  position: fixed;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: blue;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Centered divs</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="left">▢</div>

  <div id="middle"></div>

  <div id="right">▢</div>
</body>

</html>
```

How should the CSS code get modified in order for the two divs with ids `left` and `right` to get centered between the div in the middle and their respective edges of the screen? (Till now I have succeeded in centering the divs vertically and placing them on both sides of the central div, but not in centering them horizontally within the space of the central div and the screen edges.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since the middle div has a fixed width you can use some math:

```css
body {
  font-size: 30px;
}

#middle {
  width: 420px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 100px auto 0;
  border: solid;
}

#left {
  position: fixed;
  border: solid red;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%); /* updated this too */
  left: calc((100% - 420px)/4); /* half of (half the remaining space) */
}

#right {
  position: fixed;
  border: solid blue;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(50%,-50%);
  right: calc((100% - 420px)/4);
}

* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="left">▢</div>
<div id="middle"></div>
<div id="right">▢</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the best way to do this is to use flexbox

```css
body {
  
  font-size: 30px;
}
#container{
display:flex;
justify-content:space-between;
align-items:center;
}
#middle {
  width: 420px;
  height: 500px;
  
  border: solid;
}

#left {
 
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
  display:inline;
  
  
}

#right {
 
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: blue;
  display:inline;
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Centered divs</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id='container'>

  <span id="left">▢</span>

  <div id="middle"></div>

  <div id="right">▢</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The problem with this implementation is that the two side divs are not fixed!